# mutt: how to display selected new messages differently in index

Tags: mutt

I have my own colors defined for `mutt`. When I start `mutt`, the cursor (i.e., indicator) is on the first message (i.e., the first message on the top is selected). I have defined colors for the selected message, and I have colors defined for new messages as well:

```
...
color indicator color233 color67 
color index color75 color232 ~N
....
```

Unfortunately, The selected message looks the same, regardless whether the message is new or not. Is there a way to have a different color for selected new messages, so that I can immediately recognize that the selected message is new? Otherwise I have to move the cursor down, to see that the message is new.

I have tried the obvious solution:

```
color indicator color233 color67 ~N
```

but that does not work. Mutt complains:

```
Error in .muttrc, line 15: too many arguments
```

Comment: Doesn't the `N` next to it give it away?

Comment: @jasonwryan - I find the `N` in front as very inconspicuous. I usually don't notice it unless I am looking for it and I have to "read" and interpret it. Whereas, a different color would instantly strike me in the eye.

Comment: @jasonwryan FWIW this is also a problem with other kinds of colouration. For example, I have a particular colour scheme for mail with attachments (`~X 1-`), but this is also occluded by the selection highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the indicator bar to be a cursor instead, allowing you to see your colour:

```
set arrow_cursor
```

Comment: could you please elaborate how that would work ?

Comment: @MartinVegter The cursor uses a `>` at the start of the line to indicate the currently selected email line - as opposed to highlighting the entire line. It wont obscure the highlighting of that message, allowing you to see your ~N new message highlighting.